# Create a MemoryStream that covers a section of a byte array without copying the data in memory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, memorystream

I'm writing some library code, in which there is a `byte[]` that holds some data in memory. I would like to expose some part of the `byte[]` via a `Stream` object to the library consumer. For example, I would like the exposed `Stream` to be able to access the data from position 50 to the end of the `byte[]`. The exposed `Stream` would be readable and seekable, but not writable.

Is there an easy way to do this (hopefully, without writing my own `Stream` implementation) without creating a copy of the data in memory? I tried to use the new `Memory<T>` APIs, but didn't get very far because the `MemoryStream` constructor couldn't take a `Memory<T>` parameter, and it seems that I can't get a `byte[]` from `Memory<byte>` without doing a copy:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[100];
Memory<byte> memory = byteArray;

// Let's say I want to expose the second half of the byte[] via a Stream
var slicedMemory = memory.Slice(50);

// The only way to construct a MemoryStream from Memory<byte> is to call ToArray and get a byte[]
// But this makes a copy in memory, which I want to avoid
var stream = new MemoryStream(slicedMemory.ToArray(), false);
```

FYI I'm on .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `MemoryStream` - it has constructor: `MemoryStream(byte[] array, int index, int count)` which will create non-changeable stream over given array starting at requested index and having requested length.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice this constructor. Thanks a lot!